# How to prevent next focus goes away of Menu Fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

As you see in the screenshot I am working on a TV app. This screen/activity contains two fragments. The one on the left side is Menu fragment and the other one changes accordingly.

I am able to change the focus of each menu item from my keyboard (remote in case of TV). However, I want to keep the focus inside of Menu fragment when I click Top/Bottom from the keyboard. I want to switch between fragments when I click Left/Right from the keyboard.

Should I set the next focus in xml file of Menu fragment? What is your recommendation?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found my answer. I added the following attributes to each element of the menu item. It works like charm.

```
android:nextFocusUp="@id/flHome"
android:nextFocusDown="@id/flAccount"
```